# PHP Class Constructor, Not Clear On Passing in $_GET params

Tags: php, class, constructor

I have a class like this:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

class api {

    function __construct($_GET) {
        if ($_GET['method'] == "add") {
            $this->add();
        }
        else if ($_GET['method'] == "subtract") {
            $this->subtract();
        }
    }

    function add() {
        return "Adding!";
    }

    function subtract() {
        return "Subtracting!";
    }

}

$api = new api($_GET);
echo $api;
?>
```

When I send a URL from the browser of : test.php?method=add

I’m not getting any output or error messages. What I am missing?

Comment: `if` criteria need to be bracketed, e.g. `if ($_GET['method'] == "add") {` and you should be getting a syntax error message to indicate that PHP can't even compile the class file; but because it can't even compile the file, your `error_reporting()` isn't being compiled either

Comment: Whoops. Fixed that part. Still not returning anything.

Comment: PS. $_GET is a superglobal, so it doesn't need to be passed anywhere: it's always available to any function or class method

Comment: You'll also need a magic __toString() method if you want to echo a class instance like $api

Comment: @MarkBaker: Let’s pretend that $_GET will be parsed in the future and replaced by something that does need to be passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your construct function is not returning anything, only your other functions. Try this.

```
Class api {

    function __construct($_GET) {

        if ($_GET['method'] == "add") {
            $this->message =  $this->add();
        }
        else if ($_GET['method'] == "subtract") {
            $this->message =  $this->subtract();
        }
    }

    function add() {
        return "Adding!";
    }

    function subtract() {
        return "Subtracting!";
    }

}

$api = new api($_GET);
echo $api->message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your contructor to this...

```
 function __construct() {
    if(isset($_GET)){
    if($_GET['method']== "add") {
        $this->add();
    }
    else if($_GET['method'] == "subtract"){
        $this->subtract();
    }}
}
```

You don't have to pass $_GET into the construct, as its a super global and is available everywhere, all the time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

class api {

    function __construct() {
        if ($_GET['method'] == "add") {
            return $this->add();
        }
        else if ($_GET['method'] == "subtract") {
            return $this->subtract();
        }
    }

    function add() {
        return "Adding!";
    }

    function subtract() {
        return "Subtracting!";
    }

}

$api = new api();
echo $api->__construct();
?>
```

`__construct()` is the class method so in order to get the returned value from this method you have to use it this way `$api->__construct()`

Comment: Isn’t the whole point of `__construct()` so you don’t have to say it?